MariaDB problem importing timezones with mysql_tzinfo_to_sql
I use a Yocto based linux distribution with MariaDB 10.7.8. The time zones on the system based on /usr/share/zoneinfo work are:
root@mymachine:~# date
Tue Apr 16 06:05:36 UTC 2024

root@mymachine:~# TZ=Europe/Zurich date
Tue Apr 16 08:05:32 CEST 2024

I imported system time zone data to the database (like proposed from MariaDB):
root@mymachine:~# mariadb-tzinfo-to-sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql

If I check the related tables there are the time zone names
MariaDB [(none)]> select * from mysql.time_zone_name where Name like 'Europe/Zurich';
+---------------+--------------+
| Name          | Time_zone_id |
+---------------+--------------+
| Europe/Zurich |          490 |
+---------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.002 sec)

But there is no offset data:
MariaDB [(none)]> select * from mysql.time_zone_transition_type where Time_zone_id = 490;
+--------------+--------------------+--------+--------+--------------+
| Time_zone_id | Transition_type_id | Offset | Is_DST | Abbreviation |
+--------------+--------------------+--------+--------+--------------+
|          490 |                  0 |      0 |      0 |              |
+--------------+--------------------+--------+--------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

So time zone conversion with "CONVERT_TZ" gives no error but does not convert:
MariaDB [(none)]> select convert_tz("2024-04-15 08:00:00", 'UTC', 'Europe/Zurich');
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| convert_tz("2024-04-15 08:00:00", 'UTC', 'Europe/Zurich') |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 2024-04-15 08:00:00                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

Am I doing something wrong?

it muste be  mariadb-tzinfo-to-sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mariadb -u root mysql

The client mysql is a link to the client mariadb: '/usr/bin/mysql -> mariadb', so it makes no difference.
